# Pay for multiple WooCommerce orders at once

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a situation where my client want to the customers to place orders (almost reserve the product), but only pay for it after it reach the most economical postage point. They also want to discourage customers paying on an ad hoc basis as it will in crease their credit/debit card transaction fees.

Using a shipping class I can make it to 'Place the Order' instead of proceeding to payments, however is there a way I can allow customers to pay for multiple 'pending' orders at once?

Comment: Can you explain how the cart doesn't suit your needs? Why are they checking out if they aren't ready to pay?

Comment: This should be possible with a strong completely custom development, creating programmatically a new order based on all this (sub) orders customer selection in his my account order list history… Once paid this special order will update all related orders to complete (this is just an example in my brain).

Answer (score 0):

See shippingeasy.com. They do it that way now. You can get a free account and poke around.